# Docker with a Virtual Sound Card for Stream Altering

Tags: audio, docker, device

I have a docker container in which I want pass audio through, and alter sound using various standard utils before passing it onto a virtual sound card which will stream to another destination using icecast2 source.

The Host machine is a server without a sound card, and I have loaded snd_loop and exposed /dev/snd/* to docker with "docker --device /dev/snd:/dev/snd", but I still cannot access jack2, alsa or oss system in order to manipulate the stream.

Is it not possible to get a virtual sound card running in Docker?